# how to download go package in intranet env which ban specific domain

Tags: go

i'm working in intranet environment. for securify, my company ban cloud sites. so It's failed to download package from cloud.google.com domain.

```
$ go get go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/otlp/otlptrace/otlptracegrpc
go: downloading go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/otlp/otlptrace/otlptracegrpc v1.16.0
go: downloading go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/otlp/otlptrace v1.16.0
go: downloading go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/otlp v0.20.1
go: downloading go.opentelemetry.io/proto/otlp v0.19.0
go: downloading go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/otlp/internal/retry v1.16.0
go: downloading github.com/cenkalti/backoff/v4 v4.2.1
go: downloading github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2 v2.7.0
go: downloading google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20230526161137-0005af68ea54
go: downloading google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/api v0.0.0-20230525234035-dd9d682886f9
go: github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2@v2.7.0 requires
        golang.org/x/oauth2@v0.0.0-20211104180415-d3ed0bb246c8 requires
        cloud.google.com/go@v0.65.0: unrecognized import path "cloud.google.com/go": reading https://cloud.google.com/go?go-get=1: 403 New_All_deny_Page
```

I've tried to clone git repository from https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go and replace all packages. but It's very hard to download all dependencies......

And I considered using go mod vendor from my home. and then copy to my project. But I think this approach is not so good....

Is there any other solution?

Comment: "And I considered using go mod vendor from my home. and then copy to my project. But I think this approach is not so good...." This approach is "not good" only because it violates company policy. You probably should do go mod vendor from some protected/secured/guarded infrastructure _inside_ your company.

Comment: @Volker If I use 'go mod vendor' approach. I can update go.mod only in my home and I only can edit source code in company? right?

Comment: Well, basically yes. BUT: There might be a "reason" why your company forbids access to the cloud. It might be that doing "go mod vendor" at home "violates" these "reasons". Please consult your security team, your manager, whatever  before doing so. These "reasons" might be justified for legal reason, well-intended, just paranoia or even plain stupid security theater but they are in place and you probably should seek a solution, not a circumvention (which might put you in trouble).

Comment: If your company's policy prevents you from getting your work done you should talk to the company. Maybe they can give you an exception or change your requirements. I agree that you should not try to circumvent the company's wishes.